# Switch with 2 values or other mothode?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I've got 2 variables: "tl_language" and "filterLanguage".
Right now I use this code:

```
switch($GLOBALS['TL_LANGUAGE'])
                        {
                            case 'de':
                                if (!$entry->field('beschreibung')->value()){

                                    include ("includes/mediacenter_content_de.php");
                                }else{
                                    include ("includes/mediacenter_content_en.php");
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'en':
                                if (!$entry->field('beschreibung')->value()){

                                    include ("includes/mediacenter_content_en.php");
                                }else{
                                    include ("includes/mediacenter_content_de.php");
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'fr':
                                if (!$entry->field('beschreibung')->value()){

                                    include ("includes/mediacenter_content_fr.php");
                                }else{
                                    include ("includes/mediacenter_content_en.php");
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'nl':
                                if (!$entry->field('beschreibung')->value()){

                                    include ("includes/mediacenter_content_nl.php");
                                }else{
                                    include ("includes/mediacenter_content_en.php");
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                echo $entry->field('beschreibung_englisch')->value();
                                break;
                        }

                        ?>
```

Now I want to add a Filter, that the user can seperatly filter for language.
E.g. if tl_language is "de" show germ an content or if filterLanguage is "de" show german content.

Right now, I'm tring someting like this:

```
    if($GLOBALS['TL_LANGUAGE'] =="de" or $cc_language == "de"){
    if (!$entry->field('beschreibung')->value()){

        include ("includes/mediacenter_content_de.php");
    }else{
        include ("includes/mediacenter_content_en.php");
    }
}
if($GLOBALS['TL_LANGUAGE'] =="en" or $cc_language == "en"){
     if (!$entry->field('beschreibung')->value()){

        include ("includes/mediacenter_content_en.php");
    }else{
        include ("includes/mediacenter_content_de.php");
    }
}
```

But it shows double content.

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow is for helping with code, not writing code for you.

Comment: Sorry, I fergot  this. I edit the post.

Comment: The code in your `switch` statement show double code too. Your code could be a lot shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a third variable. I assume `$cc_language` has more priority. Use your first code.

```
$lang = ( isset($cc_language)  && !empty($cc_language) ) ? $cc_language : $GLOBALS['TL_LANGUAGE'];

switch( $lang ) {
```

Comment: Cool but one little problem if I select "English" on my filter, the URL looks like this: "/media-center?typ=&language=en" and the english content is shown. If I switch back to default the URL looks like this:"/media-center?typ=&language=" and nothing is shown.

Comment: Edited the condition